# how to get php to display the 2nd value of the array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

This may be a really dumb question but I'm just starting to learn the arrays function. I have this piece of code that works perfectly but only outputs the first value of the array which is [name]. I have a 2nd value in the array which is called [count] that I can't seem to get to display. What is the correct key to use?

The array output is like this:

```
[215] => Array ( [name] => Category 1 [count] => 19 )
[263] => Array ( [name] => Category 2 [count] => 12 )
```

And this is the code:

```
while ($cat_details = $db->fetch_array($sql_select_categories)) 
{ 
    $cat_array[$cat_details['category_id']]["name"]=$category_lang[$cat_details['category_id']];
    $cat_array[$cat_details['category_id']]["count"]=$cat_details['items_counter'];
}

if(is_array($cat_array)){

asort($cat_array);

    foreach($cat_array as $key => $value ){

        $subcat_link = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?parent_id=' . $key . $additional_vars;
        $output .= '<tr> '.
        '   <td class="contentfont">&nbsp;&raquo; <a href="' . $subcat_link . '">' . $category_lang[$key] . '</a></td> '.
        '</tr> ';
    }
}
```

I need to be able to display the $count somewhere in the HTML code of the foreach function. I tried everything from $cat_details[$count] to simply $count but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Inside the `foreach`, the value you want is held in `$value['count']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its inside the `foreach` you could use `$value['count']` to get the value you need

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid now. That worked! I tried about everything except that, haha. Thank you!

Comment: haha dont worry about it, i guess it happens to eveyrone mate. have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

```
$cat_array[$cat_details]['category_id']["name"]=$category_lang[$cat_details]['category_id'];
$cat_array[$cat_details]['category_id']["count"]=$cat_details['items_counter'];
```